# MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: mips

What's the difference between .s and .asm in the MIPS architecture?

Comment: Are you just asking about the file extensions?

Comment: well yes and no. i thought .s and .asm were both assembly files

Comment: The MIPS architecture doesn’t care about file extensions. That said, .s and .asm are common extensions for source files containing assembly code regardless of the target architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no innate difference between .s and .asm

If you want you can name the text file with .s and the hex file .asm but this would only be so that you could keep them straight.

Comment: if it's intel hex format, the extension can be .hex